# É possível sincronizar meus projetos do Visual Studio com outro computador?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Uso o VisualStudio no trabalho e em casa. Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira para que meus projetos que desenvolvo no PC do trabalho sejam sincronizados em meu perfil e eu possa acessá-los no computador de casa automaticamente, sem ter que copiar a pasta do VisualStudio.

Comment: Tem sim, sr. Você conhece TFS, Git ou SVN?

Comment: Não. Algum desses já é intrínseco ao VisualStudio?

Comment: O TFS é, já vem com as extensões e tudo mais. Você precisa dar uma lida sobre versionamento de código, depois que entender bem como funciona pode usar um destes para "sincronizar" seus projetos.

Comment: Obrigado, @jbueno!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma das soluções seria a utilização do [Visual Studio Team Services](http://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vso) para gerenciamento do código-fonte do seu projeto através do [Git ou TFVC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc). É gratuito para até 5 usuários.

### 1. Crie uma conta no [Visual Studio Team Services](http://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vso).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 2. Crie um novo projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 3. Após criar a conta use-a para logar-se na IDE Visual Studio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 4. Conecte ao Team Foundation Server (Visual Studio Team Services).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 5. Conecte ao endereço criado na etapa 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 6. Selecione o projeto que foi criado e clique em *Connect*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após feito este procedimento, você já pode gerenciar o seu projeto em nuvem de forma centralizada, para isso basta logar com a mesma conta no outro computador e utilizar os recursos da IDE. É importante agora aprender como funciona o mapeamento do projeto e recursos de Check-in, Get Last Version, para obter um controle do código-fonte.